# Live Edit in WebStorm remotely?

Tags: webstorm

I have `WebStorm 7` installed on machine `A`. The project files are local.

I want to use Chrome from machine `B` on the local network to debug/live edit.

In the `Debugger->Javascript`, I have "Can accept external connections" enabled. `JB` extension is also installed.

If I go on `B` Chrome and type `IPofA/prj/index.html` I can see the page. But, `Live Edit` is not available. The `JB` extension is not triggered and I 'm simply using `WebStorm` 's embedded web server.

If I click debug, `A` 's Chrome starts up (and `Live Edit` works there fine).

Is it possible to have the debugger on `A` work with Chrome on `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are instruction for connecting from different host:

- on a remote host, make sure to install JetBrains IDE Support
  extension into Chrome
- in extension options  (chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/options.html), 
  specify the IP and port of the target machine. Note that the port
  should not be 63342 - 63342 is default port number for all IDE
  services, it won't work here
- on a target computer, start WebStorm, make sure that the port  specified in Settings/JavaScript/Debugger is the same as above and
  'Can  accept external connections' is on. Open your project and run
  your  application. This should do the thing